# Sitecore 9.1 and Identity Server

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, installation

I install Sitecore XP 9.1 using SIF but identity server doesn't work. If I delete the IIS site for it I can still log into Sitecore.

Nothing in log for Sitecore or identity server. Anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

The most likely cause if you're not seeing any errors is that the new security configuration is disabled in Web.Config. It needs to be:

`<add key="security:define" value="Sitecore" />`

You can still log in to Sitecore as if it's disabled or it can't connect to the identity server it will fall back to the old sitecore login page.

You should be able to see an error in the logs if this config is enabled, but it still can't connect to the identity server:

> ERROR Unable to reach an external identity provider

The identity server URL is set by default on the `identityServerAuthority` Sitecore variable in `App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config`

Make sure that it is set correctly, that the identity server is up and running. If you go directly to your identity server URL, it should show the sitecore login page. If not, check your identity server config in `Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml` which should have correct settings for CertificateThumbprint, ConnectionString, AllowedCorsOrigins, and ClientSecrets. The ClientSecret value needs to be matching in Sitecore's ConnectionStrings.config `sitecoreidentity.secret`.